# Как заставить AdMob отображать оплачиваемую рекламу всегда, когда это возможно?

Tags: android, admob

При запуске приложения с включенным Wi-Fi все хорошо - реклама отображается (в ротации только 2 приложения, тоже подозрительно), но если Wi-Fi включать посреди сессии, то реклама не грузится. Что я сделал не так, как это исправить?
Кусок настройки AdMob из onCreate() метода.

```
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
       @Override
       public void onAdLoaded() {
           adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           super.onAdLoaded();
       }

       public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
           adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
       }
   });

    adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

**Обновление**

Никогда... то есть это:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
admobView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

После установки `layout`, в конце `onCreate`.

Comment: А запрос на показ рекламы когда делаете?

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что рекламу вы загружаете всего раз и после ошибки больше её не запрашиваете.

Так что вам надо в слушателе ошибки загрузки запрашивать её ещё раз:

```
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
   @Override
   public void onAdLoaded() {
       adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       super.onAdLoaded();
   }

   public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
       adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
       admobView.loadAd(adRequest);
       super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
   }
});

adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```